# Parsing netflow to elasticsearch through logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to parse netflow through logstash I use cisco switch to send netflow to logstash and then push flow data to elasticsearch, but it seems can't work, and this is my logstash config:

```
input{
    udp{
        host => "120.126.160.91"
        port => 5556
        codec => netflow
        type =>"netflow"

    }
}
    filter{
        if[type]=="netflow"
        {
            if "" not in [IPV4_SRC_ADDR] and "" not in [IPV6_SRC_ADDR]
            {
                drop{}
            }
        }
    }
output{
elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["120.126.160.91:9200"]
            }
    if[type]=="netflow"
    {
        stdout{codec=> rubydebug}
    }
}
```

but there seems something wrong.
logstash log:

```
Sending Logstash's logs to D:/ELK/logstash-6.1.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-01-31T17:24:52,309][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"D:/ELK/logstash-6.1.1/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2018-01-31T17:24:52,324][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"D:/ELK/logstash-6.1.1/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2018-01-31T17:24:52,651][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-01-31T17:24:53,763][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.1.1"}
[2018-01-31T17:24:54,481][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-01-31T17:25:08,371][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://120.127.160.91:9200/]}}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,250][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://120.127.160.91:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,515][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://120.127.160.91:9200/"}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,578][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>nil}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,598][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,621][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,638][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,701][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//120.127.160.91:9200"]}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,748][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>16, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2000, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3d774198 run>"}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,842][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,920][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ] Starting UDP listener {:address=>"120.127.160.91:5556"}
[2018-01-31T17:25:29,951][INFO ][logstash.inputs.udp      ] UDP listener started {:address=>"120.127.160.91:5556", :receive_buffer_bytes=>"65536", :queue_size=>"2000"}
[2018-01-31T17:25:30,013][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :pipelines=>["main"]}
```

Comment: How does it not work? Do you have output in elastic?

Comment: there's no flow data ingest into logstash. no, there's no data :(

Comment: Please try and pinpoint the location of the error. Does logstash recieve any data? Use empty filter and file output (that should pretty much work in any case). If it does add the filter and check the output. And so on.

Comment: but if I change the plugin "netflow" to "json", there are something undecoded flow data ingest into logstash.

Comment: I have no experience with netflow data processing, sry I can't help with that. I could help with the filter or the output but I have a feeling that if you get the input right the rest will be easy.

Comment: I found this, does it help? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-netflow.html

Comment: I have refered this reference. but I don't know what's wrong:(

Comment: Did you look into the logstash logs? /var/log/logstash Maybe there is some useful error message.

Comment: the log is the same above.